# What does "=R[-115]C" mean in VBA for Excel 2011 on Mac?

Tags: excel, vba, macos, excel-2011

What does "`=R[-115]C`" mean in VBA for Excel 2011 on Mac in below code?

```
Range("F171").Select    'to select a cell
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-115]C"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the offset from the cell that the formula is in.  The example you posted...

`"=R[-115]C`"

...would be offset by -115 rows in the same column, so would be equivalent to `=F56`.

You can do the same thing with the columns.  This...

```
Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[1]"
```

...would give you the formula `=B1`.

Comment: To further expand on this, the reason you would use this over say activecell.offset(0,1).formula = "=B1" is because you can do a range at once, you could say Range("A1:A120").FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[1]" and every cell in A1 to A120 would be populated with the formula = B and the row.

Comment: A range of cells can have a formula applied in either `xlA1` or `xlR1C1` manner as long as standard relative/absolute references are observed but the real advantages to R1C1 style comes in evaluating a cell to see if its conditional formatting is True or what a dynamic named range is referencing. The crux is the *Applies to:* parameter. A cell within the range of a CF formula will abide to the formula as it *Applies to:* the cell in the top-left corner; this is the same R1C1 formula for all cells in the CF's region.