# What does this line of FormulaR1C1 mean?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2016

I get what FormulaR1C1 means from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29739494/what-does-r-115c-mean-in-vba-for-excel-2011-on-mac).
But I couldn't get it when it was used with an ampersand `&` in VBA and *Vlookup* here in this line:

```
.Range(Cells(2, 3), Cells(2, 79)).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC1&R1C,POR_Vert!C4:C6,3,FALSE)"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RC1` translates to *this row*, column 1.
`R1C` translates to row 1, *this column*.

So if you're writing this formula to cells(2,3) (which is `$C$2`) then it is interpreted as:

```
"=VLOOKUP($A2 & C$1,POR_Vert!$D:$F,3,FALSE)"
```

So, for example, if $A2 contains "Searc" and C$1 contains "hKey" then it would be the equivalent of:

```
"=VLOOKUP(RC1 & R1C,POR_Vert!C4:C6,3,FALSE)"         'becomes..
"=VLOOKUP($A2 & C$1,POR_Vert!$D:$F,3,FALSE)"         'becomes..
"=VLOOKUP("Searc" & "hKey",POR_Vert!$D:$F,3,FALSE)"  'becomes..
"=VLOOKUP("SearchKey",POR_Vert!$D:$F,3,FALSE)"
```

Answer (score 0):

`&` is the concatenation operator so the lookup value is column A of the current row with row 1 of the current column appended to it. So in C2, you are taking the value of A2 and appending C1 to the end, then looking up the result.

Comment: Thank You for the quick reply! :)